# Does ASP.Net ever run in the default AppDomain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, appdomain

I've got an interesting situation where I want to make sure I'm not running in the default AppDomain on an ASP.Net Web Api service (apparently RazorEngine has issues locking temporary files if running in the default AppDomain). From what I can see, by the time `Application_Start` runs, it's already not in the default AppDomain.

Checked using: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsDefaultAppDomain()` returns `false`

Are there any situations where ASP.Net will run in the default AppDomain?

Comment: Nice question. I might misunderstand your question, but this is a setting of your web server  and the default app domain is not a setting you can choose, it is always a specific app domain (pool).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi There is no way for user code to have access to the default CLR AppDomain in ASP.NET.  The ASP.NET runtime does however use the default AppDomain for some things but it creates a specific AppDomain for running user code.  That's why IsDefaultAppDomain returns false and always will :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Add some citation of where you are getting this info from and you will get much better reaction to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, application won't run in the default domain. In one w3wp process, multiple web applications can be hosted and each of them is running in its own appdomain. Asp.net runs some code in default domain to manage those appdomains. e.g. create/unload domain, monitor process memory pressure etc..

Comment: Add some citation of where you are getting this info from and you will get much better reaction to your answer.